# Regex replace character with index of match

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I need to take this string:

```
book_id = ? and author_id = ? and publisher_id = ?
```

and turn it into this string:

```
book_id = @p1 and author_id = @p2 and publisher_id = @p3
```

using this code:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\?)", "@p **(index of group)**");
```

What is the replacement pattern to give me the index of the group?

Comment: One-liners are easy - just execute **Replace("\n", " ")** on the source code.

Comment: Very cute response ;p

Comment: Can I solve it with regex in the replacement pattern in 3rd parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`Regex.Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) that takes a `MatchEvaluator`, along with a counter variable:

```
string input = "book_id = ? and author_id = ? and publisher_id = ?";
string pattern = @"\?";
int count = 1;
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => "@p" + count++);
```

The `m =>` part is the `MatchEvaluator`. In this case there's no need to use the `Match` (which is `m`); we just want to return the concatenated result and increment the counter.

Comment: We are getting warmer with this response. However I'd need to contain the index calculation in the replacement pattern.

Comment: @schmij can you explain what you mean by index calculation of the group? My approach gives a result similar to your question. If you need the index of the `?` occurrence in the input, you can use `m.Index` in the lambda instead of the `count` variable. Or if the pattern uses a group, `@"(\?)"`, you can use `m.Groups[1].Index`. I don't think that matches your request. Maybe another example of the output will help clarify what you're after.

Comment: I'm looking for a regex-specific replacement pattern to generate the index of the matching group.

Comment: @schmij if you're looking for a solution using [regex replacement substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx), I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Posting a question to StackOverflow was my last resort. Had to create an account today to post the question.

Comment: I'm marking yours as the answer since it solves the problem. My constraints prevent me from using it unfortunately.

Comment: It gives reverse index order, results in `book_id = @p3 and author_id = @p2 and publisher_id = @p1`

Comment: @SenJacob the only way that would happen is if you're also using `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`. The code above has a result that is in order.

Comment: @AhmadMageed Yes, that makes perfect sense. I'm dealing with Hebrew text for which I added RTL option. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one line solution you could do something like, but could be slow for large strings as it has to find the count of the "?" for each match

```
 var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\?", m => "@p" + input.Take(m.Index).Count(c => c == '?'));
```

Returns `"book_id = @p0 and author_id = @p1 and publisher_id = @p2"`

This is the only way I can see to get an indext without declaring an outside variable.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with StringBuilder is not bad but isn't fastest nor most elegant :(

```cs
var count = 1;
var sb = new StringBuilder(input);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
{
    if (sb[j] == '?')
    {
        sb.Remove(i, 1);
        sb.Insert(i, "@p" + (count++));
        i += 3;
    }
}
result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have something...

The idea is to first put every index in every spot that you want indexed:

```
Ñ123456Ñ
```

For this example, there are a total of 6 items to index, so it's all of the numbers up to 6 surrounded by Ñ (or some other character that isn't anywhere else in the lookup text).

Then you manually make the very first one Ñ1Ñ, so that the regex has a starting point.
With that, the algorithm can find the last indexed one and use it to determine the index of the next one:

**Find:** `(Ñ)([0-9])(Ñ)(([^Ñ]|\r?\n)*?)(Ñ)([0-9]*)\2([0-9])([0-9]*)(Ñ)`

**Replace:** `$1$2$3$4$6$8$10`

**Text example:**

```
Ñ1Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
```

> After replacing once:

```
Ñ1Ñ
Ñ2Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
```

> After replacing again:

```
Ñ1Ñ
Ñ2Ñ
Ñ3Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
Ñ123456Ñ
```

The 'replace all' functionality won't work for this, since it has to find and replace one by one, but I think it gets the job done.

Then you just have to remove all the temporary Ñ characters and that's it.

*Disclaimer:* The part that addresses line breaks in the "in between" text - `\r?\n` - was made to work with the Atom editor, so it might need some tweaking for other situations. I believe it can actually be removed entirely, since it's included in `[^Ñ]`, but I'm not sure that'd work for other systems.

---

**For indexes with more than one digit:**

**Find:** `(Ñ)([0-9]{2})(Ñ)(([^Ñ]|\r?\n)*?)(Ñ)([0-9][0-9])*\2([0-9]{2})([0-9][0-9])*(Ñ)`

**Replace:** `$1$2$3$4$6$8$10`

**Text example:**

```
Ñ01Ñ
Ñ0102030405060708091011121314151617Ñ
Ñ0102030405060708091011121314151617Ñ
Ñ0102030405060708091011121314151617Ñ
...
```

Comment: Maybe you could add how to combine this algorithm with the code snippet OP provided?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Untested:

```
int n, i=1; while( (n=input.IndexOf("?")) != -1) { input = input.Substring(0,n-1) + "@p" + (++i) + input.Substring(n+1); }
```

A longish line, but not completely unreasonable.

Comment: Yes it's one line.. but I'm not entirely sure that is what the OP was aiming for..